# Display Laravel blade template code in a blade template without execution

Tags: php, laravel

I need to display this code in Laravel blade template but the code gets executed instead of just displaying:

This needs to be displayed: 
    {{ Ads::Display('ad_id') }}

The problem is that the code above is used to actually display an ad in template, and in this context it shouldn't be executed, just displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to display a string that is wrapped in curly braces, you may escape the Blade behavior by prefixing your text with an @ symbol:

```
@{{ Ads::Display('ad_id') }}
```

As described in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

Answer (score 0):

After reading through Laravel blade template documentation, I've found solution under the subtitle "Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces"

The solution is to use "@" symbol before the code and it won't be executed as a blade tempalte code, just displayed.

So the final solution is:

```
@{{ Ads::Display('ad_id') }}
```